# Services failing to start during restart and not all time

Tags: java, jboss-eap-6, switchyard, redhat-openjdk

Iam facing a wierd issue.Services are failing to start sometimes after restart of server.if i undeploy and deploy the same jar the application is started successfully.The jar is not corrupted.
Iam running the JBoss EAP 6.1 server in linux platform.
JDK installed is openjdk 1.7

```
Server logs :
    2017-08-04 02:09:56,449 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-23) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."GGInWrite.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."GGInWrite.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "GGInWrite.jar"
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.3.Final-redhat-2-bz-1174871.jar:7.2.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
      at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:634) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:412) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:162) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1048) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at org.switchyard.common.io.pull.Puller.pull(Puller.java:101)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.Descriptor.addDefaultProperties(Descriptor.java:145)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.Descriptor.addDefaultProperties(Descriptor.java:132)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.Descriptor.addDefaultProperties(Descriptor.java:124)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.Descriptor.<init>(Descriptor.java:93)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.ModelPuller.<init>(ModelPuller.java:52)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.ModelPuller.<init>(ModelPuller.java:44)
      at org.switchyard.as7.extension.deployment.SwitchYardConfigProcessor.deploy(SwitchYardConfigProcessor.java:59)
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.3.Final-redhat-2-bz-1174871.jar:7.2.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
      ... 5 more


    2017-08-04 02:09:56,426 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."DocumentEuDeferredDispatcher.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."DocumentEuDeferredDispatcher.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "DocumentEuDeferredDispatcher.jar"
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.3.Final-redhat-2-bz-1174871.jar:7.2.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
      at org.switchyard.config.model.Descriptor.addDefaultProperties(Descriptor.java:154)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.Descriptor.addDefaultProperties(Descriptor.java:132)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.Descriptor.addDefaultProperties(Descriptor.java:124)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.Descriptor.<init>(Descriptor.java:93)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.ModelPuller.<init>(ModelPuller.java:52)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.ModelPuller.<init>(ModelPuller.java:44)
      at org.switchyard.as7.extension.deployment.SwitchYardConfigProcessor.deploy(SwitchYardConfigProcessor.java:59)
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.3.Final-redhat-2-bz-1174871.jar:7.2.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
      ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
      at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.ensureOpen(InflaterInputStream.java:67) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:503) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
      at org.switchyard.common.io.pull.PropertiesPuller.pull(PropertiesPuller.java:39)
      at org.switchyard.common.io.pull.PropertiesPuller.pull(PropertiesPuller.java:30)
      at org.switchyard.common.io.pull.Puller.pull(Puller.java:103)
      at org.switchyard.config.model.Descriptor.addDefaultProperties(Descriptor.java:145)
      ... 12 more
```

Comment: Stream types (like StreamSource, InputStream and Reader) are commonly used in messaging for performance reasons, they also have an important drawback: they can only be read once. In order to be able to work with message content multiple times, the stream needs to be cached. For more details refer: (http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html)

Comment: Hi Anup,I do not understand the context here.i do understand enabling streaming in camel route means reading the message only once.But iam getting this error during deployment time how does this relate with camel streaming option?

Comment: - Check network issues with remote system. I am assuming that you are trying to deploy through the management console. There was an issue with too short timeout...Try to use with JBoss EAP 6.4.x/7.0.x which contains no. of improvement and security fixes.

Comment: We are not doing deployments from admin console.we do hot deployments copying jar files into deployments directory

Comment: I  assume that when you put the declaration ZipFile instance of  within the try it will not be closed (note that this should then be done somewhere after out.close(). Check your code..

There's documented behavior in : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#close--

Closing this ZIP file will close all of the input streams previously returned by invocations of the getInputStream method.

A Java 7 try-with-resources(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement calls close automatically at the end of the block.)